# Who made the dinosaurs puppets in Prehysteria?

Tags: props, prehysteria

**Question:** Who made the Baby dinosaurs puppets in Prehysteria?

**About the Movie:** Prehysteria is a movie released in 1993. It about a group of kids that find these baby dinosaurs after after they hatch and keep them as pets. I Don't remember the rest of the plot but the idea of having pet dinosaurs is awesome!

Trying to find out who made the baby dinosaurs.

I thought the answer Charles Robert Band but I am not quite sure. Charles Robert Band is famous for the Puppet Master franchise. That why I think it is him.

**Also:** Can someone suggest better tags please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The People responsible for making the dinosaurs are:** 
Anthony Allen Barlow    ... special effects artist (as Allen Barlow)
Steven Barr ... puppeteer
Angela Chao ... special effects production
David Dupuis    ... special effects artist
Jurgen Heimann  ... special effects
Kevin O'Hara    ... special effects mechanic
Mark Rappaport  ... puppet effects supervisor (as Mark A. Rappaport)
Kirk Skodis ... special effects mechanic
Shaun Smith ... special effects artist
**Thank You for your help**
Paulie_D